# Get specific data from site using Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to get 4 data points from website, I am able to get first, but due to my novice skills I am having difficulty in getting other three. Here is the screenshot of webpage:

[image: ScrapeData]

I was able to get `No. 1037325` from the following script:

```
function extractDataFromUrl() {

  var url = "https://h3p1c2bj.r.us-east-1.awstrack.me/L0/https:%2F%2Fduproprio.com%2Fen%2F1037325%3Futm_source=alerts%26utm_medium=email%26utm_campaign=qc-en-property%26utm_content=photo-propriete-2/1/0100018712213f2c-181f0f4a-951f-46e5-bc01-c2dc66276552-000000/ObF-c1cmnxhP6DpL7H7kY5QaxH0=314";

  // Fetch the contents of the redirected URL
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const regex = /#(\d+)/;
  const match = regex.exec(response);
  const result = match ? match[1] : null;

   Logger.log(result)  //1037325
 
}
```

Can you please guide how to get other data points? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try using this String.match(/\d+/g)

Comment: thank you for your answer, however it does not give required phone numbers.

Comment: This does `String.match(/[0123456789-]/g)`

Comment: no, it gives weird output with large number of digits

Comment: I would need some sample data and I'm not going to go to the url myself because I'm not familiar with it.  So you will have to figure it out yourself. Try using regex101.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function extractPhoneNumbers(url) {
 // Fetch the page content
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
 var htmlContent = response.getContentText();

 // Create a regular expression to match the phone number pattern
 var regex = /<span class="listing-contact__number">\s*([\d-]+)\s*<\/span>/g;

 // Execute the regular expression on the HTML content
 var match;
 var phoneNumbers = [];

 while ((match = regex.exec(htmlContent)) !== null) {
  if (match[1]) {
   phoneNumbers.push(match[1]);
  }
 }

 // Log the extracted phone numbers
 if (phoneNumbers.length > 0) {
  Logger.log("Phone numbers: " + phoneNumbers.join(', '));
 } else {
  Logger.log("No phone numbers found.");
 }
}

function testExtractPhoneNumbers() {
 var url = 'https://duproprio.com/en/montreal/verdun/condo-for-sale/hab-395-rue-melrose-1022529?position=45.45362843523109%2C-73.57327222824098&zoom=15';
 extractPhoneNumbers(url);
}
```

Comment: I used a different post from the website just to verify that the code works well for any property.

Comment: Thank you, it works correctly to get phone number, can we get the point 4 as well, as it is mentioned in the screenshot?

Comment: var regex = /<p class="listing-contact__no-solicitations-nb">\s*<span class="listing-contact__no-solicitations-nb-icon">[\s\S]*?<\/span>\s*([\s\S]*?)\s*<\/p>/;